# Java Calculating MPG Error

Tags: java, class, math, syntax-error, driver

I've been having trouble with this assignment where I'm supposed to calculate the the Miles per gallon of a certain inputted variable.

The assignment's specifications are: http://www.mrferrante.com/apcs/WebLessons/LessonA4/images/Lab_A1_fig_1.gif

and I am supposed to calculate MPG

here is my Driver:

```
public class Driver{
        public static void main(String[] args){
        int odometerReading = 15;    
        P4_Icel_Murad_Car auto = new P4_Icel_Murad_Car(odometerReading);

        System.out.println("New car odometer reading: " + startMiles);
        auto.fillUp(150,8);
        System.out.println("Miles per gallon: " + auto.calculateMPG());
        System.out.println("Miles per gallon: " + auto.calculateMPG());
        auto.resetMPG();
        auto.fillUp(350, 10);
        auto.fillUp(450, 20);
        System.out.println("Miles per gallon: " + auto.calculateMPG());
        auto.resetMPG();
        auto.fillUp(603, 25.5);
        System.out.println("Miles per gallon: " + auto.calculateMPG());

    }
}
```

and here is the rest of the code:

```
public class P4_Icel_Murad_Car{
    private int myStartMiles;
    private int myEndMiles;
    private double myGallonsUsed;
    public int P4_Icel_Murad_Car(int odometerReading){
     myStartMiles = odometerReading;
     return myStartMiles;
    }
    public void fillUp(int odometerReading,double gallons){
        int Miles = odometerReading - myStartMiles;
        double MilesPerGallon = Miles / gallons;
    }
    public double calculateMPG( int odometerReading, double gallons){
        int MPG = (int)(odometerReading/gallons);
        return MPG;
    }
    public void resetMPG(){
        myStartMiles = 0;
        myEndMiles = 0;
        myGallonsUsed = 0;
    }
}
```

when inputing 15 as startMiles, the result should be

```
New car odometer reading: 15
    Miles per gallon: 16.875
    Miles per gallon: 16.875
    Miles per gallon: 10.0
    Miles per gallon: 6.0
```

but the IDE I'm using (BlueJ) claims that P4_Icel_Murad_Car() doesn't need any args and that I'm putting in int instead of nothing.
Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have several mistakes in your code, here is working version with comments:

```
public static class P4_Icel_Murad_Car {
    private int myStartMiles;
    private int myEndMiles;
    private double myGallonsUsed;

    public P4_Icel_Murad_Car(final int odometerReading) { // Constructor does not have return type, do not put int before constructor name
        this.myStartMiles = odometerReading;
        this.myEndMiles = odometerReading; // init end miles with start miles from the start
        this.myGallonsUsed = 0;
    }

    public void fillUp(final int odometerReading, final double gallons) {
        this.myEndMiles = odometerReading; // store current odometer
        this.myGallonsUsed += gallons; // sum up gas
    }

    public double calculateMPG() { // calculate mileage, divide by gallons
        return (this.myEndMiles - this.myStartMiles) / this.myGallonsUsed;
    }

    public void resetMPG() { // reset means start from current odometer reading
        this.myStartMiles = this.myEndMiles;
        this.myGallonsUsed = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your class is called `P4_Icel_Murad_Car`.

So `P4_Icel_Murad_Car` should be the constructor for the class, you must not return an `int` from it.

Try replacing that method with:

```
    public P4_Icel_Murad_Car(int odometerReading){
         myStartMiles = odometerReading;
    }
```